# Find number of k-permutation with ordering but no repetition

Tags: permutation, combinations, combinatorics

Im truggling to find a closed form for the number of *k-permutations* of a set *S* of *cardinality n*.

The combinations should regard ordering, but no repitions.

Example:

```
|S| = n = 3 
S = {a,b,c}
k = 2

{a,b}
{b,a}
{b,c}
{c,b}
{a,c}
{c,a}
```

Anyone could help me out how to compute the number of viable permutations (and not the permutations itself)?

What I've tried:
I've read through different material and found out, that including repitititions it is

```
O(n) = n^k
```

My initial though was, that I need to eliminiate the permutations like

```
{a,a}
{b,b}
{c,c}
```

But I struggle finding a closed form for the number of perceivable repititions.

Comment: have you tried asking at http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the number of k-permutations of a set S of cardinality n.

The formulae is well known : n!/(n-k)!

Pseudo-proof :

- for the 1st element, you are able to choose among the n elements of S ;
- for the 2nd, only among : n-1, because you don't want doublons ;
- ...
- for the ith, only among : n-(i-1) ;
- ...
- for the kth, only among : n-(k-1) ;

So, finally :
n * (n-1) * ... * (n-i) * ... * (n-k+1)
= n! / (n-k)!